# compare two list and return not matching items using linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, c#-4.0

i have a two list

```
List<Sent> SentList;
List<Messages> MsgList;
```

both have the same property called MsgID;

```
MsgList            SentList  

MsgID Content      MsgID Content Stauts
1       aaa        1       aaa     0
2       bbb        3       ccc     0
3       ccc        
4       ddd
5       eee
```

i want to compare the MsgID in Msglist with the sentlist and need items which are not in the sent list using linq

```
Result 

MsgID Content
2       bbb
4       ddd
5       eee
```

Answer (score 56):

You could do something like:

```
HashSet<int> sentIDs = new HashSet<int>(SentList.Select(s => s.MsgID));

var results = MsgList.Where(m => !sentIDs.Contains(m.MsgID));
```

This will return all messages in `MsgList` which don't have a matching ID in `SentList`.

Comment: This is probably the best approach

Comment: What if you need to compare more than one property? (Id and version number for example?

Comment: @NickG then you create a class for it implementing IEqualityComparer<T> and make a `HashSet<className>` instead.

Answer (score 35):

The naive approach:

```
MsgList.Where(x => !SentList.Any(y => y.MsgID == x.MsgID))
```

Be aware this will take up to `m*n` operations as it compares every `MsgID` in `SentList` to each in `MsgList` ("up to" because it will short-circuit when it *does* happen to match).

Comment: If you're going to downvote, you could at least do me the common courtesy of explaining why.

Comment: How about: `MsgList.Where(x => SentList.All(y => y.MsgID == x.MsgID))`

Comment: @zumalifeguard I presume you mean `!=` and if so yes it's a logically equivalent expression which should take the same amount of time.

Answer (score 21):

Well, you already have good answers, but they're most Lambda. A more LINQ approach would be like

```
var NotSentMessages =
                from msg in MsgList
                where !SentList.Any(x => x.MsgID == msg.MsgID)
                select msg;
```

Comment: `var NotSentMessages =
                from msg in MsgList
                where !SentList.Any(x => x.MsgID == msg.MsgID && x.content == msg.content) 
                select msg;` 

This is better for comparision of multiple properties (combined keys)

Comment: @AndrewDay yeah but OP said he wanted to check equal IDs, so there's no need to match strings here.

Comment: - so your code is better code because its extendable.  But thats a bad comment????

Comment: @AndrewDay not at all man, I'm just explaining why I only matched IDs. :)

Comment: @AndreCalil Calil: LINQ supports two syntaxes... "Query syntax and method syntax are semantically identical..." from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq

Answer (score 10):

You can do like this,this is the quickest process

```
Var result = MsgList.Except(MsgList.Where(o => SentList.Select(s => s.MsgID).ToList().Contains(o.MsgID))).ToList();
```

This will give you expected output.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're making a list from SentList on each iteration in the Where function. There's no way that could be efficient. store `SentList.Select(s => s.MsgID).ToList()` in a variable outside of the where statement first.

Answer (score 9):

You can do something like

```
var notSent = MsgSent.Except(MsgList, MsgIdEqualityComparer);
```

You will need to provide a custom equality comparer as outlined on MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx

Simply have that equality comparer base equality only on MsgID property of each respective type.  Since the equality comparer compares two instances of the same type, you would need to define an interface or common base type that both *Sent* and *Messages* implement that has a *MsgID* property.

Answer (score 5):

In **.NET 6** you can take advantage of [`.ExceptBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.exceptby?view=net-6.0), which lets you define which property of the first list to compare the items in the second list by:

```csharp
List<Message> result = messages
    .ExceptBy(sentList.Select(msg => msg.MsgID), msg => msg.MsgID)
    .ToList();
```

`messages` is the first list, whereas a collection of the `MsgID` properties from `sentList` is the second list.

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fVOgaQ).

---

**Note:**
`.ExceptBy()` produces the *set difference* between the two collections --> only distinct values will be in the resulting collection. This means that if `messages` contains the same value more than once (e.g. `{ "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "ddd", "eee" }`), any duplicates will be removed in the resulting collection (--> `{ "bbb", "ddd", "eee" }`).

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
  public class Sent
{
    public int MsgID;
    public string Content;
    public int Status;

}

public class Messages
{
    public int MsgID;
    public string Content;
}

  List<Sent> SentList = new List<Sent>() { new Sent() { MsgID = 1, Content = "aaa", Status = 0 }, new Sent() { MsgID = 3, Content = "ccc", Status = 0 } };
            List<Messages> MsgList = new List<Messages>() { new Messages() { MsgID = 1, Content = "aaa" }, new Messages() { MsgID = 2, Content = "bbb" }, new Messages() { MsgID = 3, Content = "ccc" }, new Messages() { MsgID = 4, Content = "ddd" }, new Messages() { MsgID = 5, Content = "eee" }};

            int [] sentMsgIDs = SentList.Select(v => v.MsgID).ToArray();
            List<Messages> result1 = MsgList.Where(o => !sentMsgIDs.Contains(o.MsgID)).ToList<Messages>();
```

Hope it should help.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> AreNotEqual<TSource, TKey, TTarget>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> sourceKeySelector, IEnumerable<TTarget> target, Func<TTarget, TKey> targetKeySelector) 
{
    var targetValues = new HashSet<TKey>(target.Select(targetKeySelector));

    return source.Where(sourceValue => targetValues.Contains(sourceKeySelector(sourceValue)) == false);
}
```

eg.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}

public class OtherCustomer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}


var customers = new List<Customer>()
{
    new Customer() { CustomerId = 1 },
    new Customer() { CustomerId = 2 }
};

var others = new List<OtherCustomer>()
{
    new OtherCustomer() { Id = 2 },
    new OtherCustomer() { Id = 3 }
};

var result = customers.AreNotEqual(customer => customer.CustomerId, others, other => other.Id).ToList();

Debug.Assert(result.Count == 1);
Debug.Assert(result[0].CustomerId == 1);
```

Comment: Is ti possible to use multiple properties for the selectors?

Comment: @Rebecca  I think this would work :)

var result = customers
    .AreNotEqual(customer => (customer.CustomerId, customer.CustomerName), others, other => (other.Id, other.Name))            
    .ToList();

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Person> persons1 = new List<Person>
           {
                    new Person {Id = 1, Name = "Person 1"},
                    new Person {Id = 2, Name = "Person 2"},
                    new Person {Id = 3, Name = "Person 3"},
                    new Person {Id = 4, Name = "Person 4"}
           };


        List<Person> persons2 = new List<Person>
           {
                    new Person {Id = 1, Name = "Person 1"},
                    new Person {Id = 2, Name = "Person 2"},
                    new Person {Id = 3, Name = "Person 3"},
                    new Person {Id = 4, Name = "Person 4"},
                    new Person {Id = 5, Name = "Person 5"},
                    new Person {Id = 6, Name = "Person 6"},
                    new Person {Id = 7, Name = "Person 7"}
           };
        var output = (from ps1 in persons1
                      from ps2 in persons2
                      where ps1.Id == ps2.Id
                      select ps2.Name).ToList();
```

Person class

```
public class Person
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }       

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u wanna Select items of List from 2nd list:

MainList.Where(p => 2ndlist.Contains(p.columns from MainList )).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

make single list and
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.BillId).Where(x => x.Count() == 1).Select(x => x.First());

Answer (score -1):

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>() {  new Car() { Name = "Ford", Year = 1892, Website = "www.ford.us" }, 
                                    new Car() { Name = "Jaguar", Year = 1892, Website = "www.jaguar.co.uk" }, 
                                    new Car() { Name = "Honda", Year = 1892, Website = "www.honda.jp"} };

List<Factory> factories = new List<Factory>() {     new Factory() { Name = "Ferrari", Website = "www.ferrari.it" }, 
                                                    new Factory() { Name = "Jaguar", Website = "www.jaguar.co.uk" }, 
                                                    new Factory() { Name = "BMW", Website = "www.bmw.de"} };

foreach (Car car in cars.Where(c => !factories.Any(f => f.Name == c.Name))) {
    lblDebug.Text += car.Name;
}
```

Comment: Ah, exactly the same solution as lc. posted. But, well, here you have it with a full and tested example.