# Take value from part of a LINQ query and add it to the result

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I am comparing two `ObservableCollections` of `LayerModel` called `SourceDrawingLayers` and `TargetDrawingLayers`.

The `LayerModel` has properties like this:

```
public string Path { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
//etc
```

The program asks the user to select .dwg files that I call `TargetDrawings`. For each one I capture the layers from that file and properties of those layers. Each layer found in the drawing returns a `LayerModel` and the properties on `LayerModel` such as `Path` `Name` `Color` etc are populated by looking at the actual drawing file that I'm reading. All of those `LayerModel`s are added to `TargetDrawingLayers`.

So `TargetDrawingLayers` will contain a whole bunch of `LayerModel`s and on them I am using the `Path` property to know which actual drawing file a given layer exists in.

`SourceDrawingLayers` is populated by reading a single drawing file, reading all of the layers in that, and adding them to the collection.

My expectation is every `TargetDrawing` will contain the same layers with the same settings as the `SourceDrawing` so I accomplish that by first matching the name of a `LayerModel` in `SourceDrawingLayers` to a `LayerModel` in `TargetDrawingLayers`.

One of the requirements of the application, however, is I need to identify any `LayerModel` in `SourceDrawingLayers` whose `Name` property is not found in `TargetDrawingLayers`.

I accomplish this with the following query:

```
        var missingLayerQuery = SourceDrawingLayers.Where(p => !TargetDrawingLayers.Any(p2 => p2.Name == p.Name));
        ObservableCollection<LayerModel> q = new ObservableCollection<LayerModel>(missingLayerQuery);
```

The result is bound to a `DataGrid` and on it I need to display the name of the layer that is missing which my query accomplishes but because the query result is a collection of `LayerModels` from the source my column for Path is just showing the path of the source drawing, so my result will look something like this:

```
Drawing Path                    Layer Name
Awesome_Source_Drawing.dwg      MissingLayerName1
Awesome_Source_Drawing.dwg      MissingLayerName2
Awesome_Source_Drawing.dwg      MissingLayerName3
```

That ends up not being so useful because the user does not know what drawing is actually missing the layer that needs to be there. The result that I *want* is this:

```
Drawing Path                    Layer Name
Test_Drawing_1.dwg              MissingLayerName1
Test_Drawing_2.dwg              MissingLayerName2
Test_Drawing_3.dwg              MissingLayerName3
```

My idea was to add a property to my `LayerModel` called `public string MissingLayer {get; set;}` and then find a way to populate it from the LINQ query by looking at the particular `TargetDrawingLayers` `LayerModel` and setting the value that way.

But that is where I am stuck because I'm still not quite familiar enough with LINQ to pull it off. I'm also not sure if there's a better/easier way to go about it. So my question is, how can I accomplish my desired outcome using this LINQ query, and if I can't, what's a good way to go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: There is linq api called `except`.Please look at this thread.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957685/compare-two-list-and-return-not-matching-items-using-linq

Comment: Thanks Jagadeesh I will check those answers out too.

Comment: Where `Test_Drawing_1.dwg` comes from? can you put an example of `SourceDrawingLayers` and `TargetDrawingLayers` to your question?

Comment: If you don't want to display the path of the source drawing, what path do you want to display? Where does it come from?

Comment: @fenixil, I will update my question with more info. Thanks.

Comment: @mm8 I would like to display the Path property of the target `LayerModel` that the source `Name` property is not found in. I've updated my question with more info.

Comment: Where do you get a reference to the object that contains that path that you want to display?

Comment: @mm8

I'm actually starting to think I need to take a minute to really re-think what I'm trying do. I may have overcomplicated things. Basically I have two collections. I need to compare them, find the ones that exist on collection A but not B. I need to report the Bs that aren't found in A.

I've since tried `var query = CollectionB.Except(CollectionA);` but this returns everything because none of these things are equal. They all have a different `Path` property at least. I need to basically do something like `var query = CollectionB.Except(CollectionA)On(Name)` property.

Comment: @RickPangburn thanks for details explanation, but I still do not get where `Test_Drawing_1.dwg` comes from. Can you put an example something like: `SourceDrawingLayers = {{Path=A, Layer=L1},{Path=A, Layer=L2},{Path=B, Layer=L2}} ; TargetDrawingLayers = {{Path=A, Layer=L1}}; ExpectedResult= {???}`

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the names, you should only select the names;

```cs
SourceDrawingLayers.Where( ... ).Select(p => p.Name);
```

You might also wish to create a `HashSet<string>` of the layer names to efficiently handle thousands of layers.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. Can you help me out with the second half? Since this changes the query to return strings how can I populate the ObservableCollection?

`var missingLayerQuery = SourceDrawingLayers.Where(p => !TargetDrawingLayers.Any(p2 => p2.Name == p.Name)).Select(p => p.Name);`

I am overriding GetHashCode on my LayerModel. Basically I have `if(This == null)
{
return 0
}`

And then for each property I have a line like

`int PathHashCode = Path == null ? 0 : Path.GetHashCode();`

And finally `return PathHashCode ^` for each property.

Does that look right?

Comment: If you just need the LayerModels with names from missingLayerQuery, you can just do SourceDrawingLayers.Where(x=> missingLayerQuery.Contains(x.Name)); Its kinda hard to follow what you're asking for.